# PHP - Getting an XML file that is echoed in another PHP file, then saving the echoed XML output to the server

Tags: php, xml, file-io

I have an PHP file - called `xml_generate.php` - that creates a DOM object and echoes it at the very end.

Lets say it looks like this:

```
header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$node = $dom->createElement('foo');
$root = $dom->appendChild($node);

$node = $dom->createElement('bar');
$new_node = $root->appendChild($node);

echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I'm accessing this file from jQuery and displaying the content on the client-side. The actual xml_generate.php creates the DOM dynamically from a database.

However, I want to have a PHP file that will create a backup of the XML generated by generate_xml.php and save it to the server.

So, I need to somehow access that XML document (the one that is dynamically created in xml_generate.php).

I've tried a a few different functions to get the XML from xml_generate.php, for instance:

`$xml = http_get('xml_generate.php');`,

`$xml = file_get_contents('xml_generate.php');`

as well as just including the first file (`include('xml_generate.php')`, then just trying to access the `$dom` variable in that file).

but I can't seem to get it right. Any ideas on the best approach to do this?

Comment: Why not just create a backup from the `generate_xml.php` script?

Comment: Because the backups will be made independently of xml_generate.php being called to provide data for the client-side; I don't want a backup to be created every time the xml_generate.php is requested. I suppose I could make the functionality conditional upon a parameter in the request though, and then have the backup feature call it with  `xml_generate.php?backup=true`, or something to that affect

Comment: That would be an easier solution that what you're trying to do. You could keep all the functionality in one file.

Comment: cool, that worked. thanks! although i'm still curious why I couldn't get it the other way

Comment: You definitely could and I could answer it below if you're curious but you came up with a much better way to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Output Buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php), which will buffer any data sent to the output stream, and then retrieve that after including your script:

```
ob_start();
include "xml_generate.php";
$xml = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Make sure to catch errors @"xml_generate.php" though, or these will be buffered as well and you'll end up with an invalid xml backup.

Comment: ok output buffering sounds like the right track. I still can't seem to get the data from it though. I've done the code above as you suggested, then create a new DOM (`$doc = new DOMDocument();`), load the XML from the output buffer (`$doc->loadXML($xml);`), then attempting to echo that XML (`echo $doc->saveXML();`, just so I can see that it's actually getting through). It's just giving me an empty XML file though. Am I misunderstanding the way I need to go about _getting_ the actual XML out of it?

Comment: I also tried using `load($xml)`, as well as `echo($xml)` and `print_r($xml)` just for yuks, none of them output anything though

Comment: You can't pass arguments this way (building = 300). You'll have to use a variable that both scripts know - the backup script might set "$building = 300;" and the xml script uses it if(!isset($_GET["Building"])) (at least im guessing thats how you do it)

Comment: also, that include should've thrown warnings, it is best to activate strict error reporting to debug your code: error_reporting(E_ALL);